# Angular - Keep mat-button-toggle checked after a page refresh with value stored in localStorage

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage

I have a mat-button-toggle group and when I check a button on it, it stores a value in localStore.

And I want to get the value stored in the localStorage and after a page refresh keep the mat-button-toggle checked in fonction of the stored value in the localStorage.

Here is my **component.html** :

```
<p>
    <mat-button-toggle-group>
        <mat-button-toggle class="grille" (click)="callSwitchGrille()">
            <app-icon nomIcon="grille" [stroke]=true [size]="'1.8'"></app-icon> Grille
        </mat-button-toggle>

        <mat-button-toggle class="tableau" (click)="callSwitchTableau()">
            <app-icon nomIcon="tableau" [stroke]=true [size]="'1.8'"></app-icon> Tableau
        </mat-button-toggle>
    </mat-button-toggle-group>
</p>
```

So I can switch between "Grille" and "Tableau" and so I store "grille" or "tableau" in the localStorage and I'd like that if "grille" is stored the button stays checked on "Grille".

Here is my **component.ts** where I store the data :

```
constructor(private localStorageService : LocalStorageService) { }

  setDisplayMode(mode:DisplayMode){
    this.displayMode=mode;
    this.displayModeChanged.emit(this.displayMode);
    localStorage.setItem('displayModeKey', this.displayMode)
  }
  
  callSwitchGrille(){
    this.setDisplayMode(DisplayMode.GRILLE)
  }
  
  callSwitchTableau(){
    this.setDisplayMode(DisplayMode.TABLEAU)
  }
}
```

I tried a lot of different things and it's not working as I want, so if you could help me I would really appreciate.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I created a class just to explain the whole stuff but in your case, it could be an existing component where you are already working on

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-experiments",
  templateUrl: "./experiments.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./experiments.component.scss"],
})
export class ExperimentsComponent implements OnInit {
  displayMode: string;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.displayMode = localStorage.getItem("displayModeKey");
  }

  setDisplayMode(mode: string) {
    localStorage.setItem("displayModeKey", mode);
    this.displayMode = mode;
  }
}
```

.html file

```
<p>
  <mat-button-toggle-group>
    <mat-button-toggle
      [ngClass]="{ grille: displayMode === 'grille' }"
      (click)="setDisplayMode('grille')"
    >
      <app-icon nomIcon="grille" [stroke]="true" [size]="'1.8'"></app-icon>
      Grille
    </mat-button-toggle>

    <mat-button-toggle
      [ngClass]="{ tableau: displayMode === 'tableau' }"
      (click)="setDisplayMode('tableau')"
    >
      <app-icon nomIcon="tableau" [stroke]="true" [size]="'1.8'"></app-icon>
      Tableau
    </mat-button-toggle>
  </mat-button-toggle-group>
</p>
```

.scss or .css file

```
.grille {
  border: 4px rgb(170, 231, 0) solid;
}

.tableau {
  border: 4px #c03 solid;
}
```